# ¿Como asignar los parametros de una función a un objeto en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Lo que necesito sabes es como asignar los parámetros que me entran de una función a los atributos de un objeto.

Estoy intentando de esta manera pero el editor me tira error:

```
function realizaProceso(nodoHpi, nombreIndice, valorIndice){
    $('#formulario').on('submit', (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    var parametros = `{"index": `$nodoHpi`, "name": `$nombreIndice`, "value": `$valorIndice`}`;
    var json = JSON.stringify(parametros);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` no recibe cadenas, haz así:

```
function realizaProceso(nodoHpi, nombreIndice, valorIndice){
    $('#formulario').on('submit', (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    var parametros = {"index": nodoHpi, "name":nombreIndice, "value":  valorIndice};
    var json = JSON.stringify(parametros);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes asignarlos directamente sobre tu var de parametros

```
function realizaProceso(nodoHpi, nombreIndice, valorIndice){    
    var parametros = JSON.stringify({
        index: nodoHpi,
        name: nombreIndice,
        value: valorIndice
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let parametros = {
    "index": nodoHpi,
    "name": nombreIndice,
    "value": valorIndice
};
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, las respuestas que son solo código generalmente no son buenas, agrega información a tu respuesta, revisa [answer] para realizar buenas respuestas, saludos.